# Integral solution needed containing indicator function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, stochastic-integrals

I want to solve the following integral $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbb{1}(x\in C) \, dx$$  where $\mathbb{1}$ is the indicator function and $C$ is a subset of Borel $\sigma$ algebra $B(\mathbb{R}^2)$. My above integral is similar to the integral present in Lemma 1 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6122v1.pdf . I do not know how to solve this integral. Please help in solving this.

Comment: "and $C$ is some constant" ?? I doubt that. Rather, $C$ is probably some (measurable) subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and then the integral is the area of $C$.

Comment: The paper you cite refers to $1(x\in A)$ where $A$ is a Borel set, not where $A$ is "some constant".  To say that $x\in\text{some constant}$ doesn't make sense. $\qquad$

Comment: Then the integral is a random variable equal to the area of $\chi^{1/\alpha}A$, which is the area of $A$ times $\chi^{2/\alpha}$. (No, you cannot ask readers to open a PDF to understand the question, which should be self-contained.)

Comment: @Did thank you so much. Can you tell me how you calculated the area to be $A \chi^{\frac{2}{\alpha}}$ (I know its very basic but I am struggling with this since last 6 hours, any reference that discusses this scaling of area (a measurable subset $A$ multiplied with some constant $C$ will result in area of $CA$ to be $AC^2$) will also be grateful). Many thanks in advance

Comment: Change of variable tells you that $$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(t^{-1}x)dx=|t|^{2}\iint_{\mathbb R^2}f(x)dx$$ Use this with $$f(x)=\mathbf 1(x\in A)\qquad t=\chi^{1/\alpha}$$

Comment: @Did Thank you for your response. As you mentioned I checked the general form of substitution of variable in double integration which is given below $$\int\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y)dxdy=\int\int_{S}f(g(u,v),h(u,v))\left|\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right|dudv$$In my formula I do not know how to split $x$ into two variables. In essence I am unable to understand the value of Jacobian to be $|t|^2$ in your expression. This is because I  do not know how to split the variables. Is it possible to add more detail in the first equation of your comment. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Did I also removed the comments that mention to open the PDF.

Comment: Use the change of variable $$(u,v)=(tx,ty)$$

Comment: @Did yes I am finally able to understand it. $$\int \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(t^{-1}x,t^{-1}y)dxdy=|t|^2\int \int_{S}f(u,v)dudv$$ with the change of variable $u=t^{-1}x, v=t^{-1}y$. Thank you Did for your help in making me understand. (Note: I used $u=t^{-1}x, v=t^{-1}y$ instead of $u=tx, v=ty$ I think my substitution is right but if I am wrong then please comment on this)